# Android: Update ListView Items every 1 minute

Tags: android, listview

I have a Custom ListView in my application, containing an ImageView and 3-5 TextViews.

1 of the TextViews shows the time gap between the **current time** and the **time specified** for that ListView item.

Like: *Posted 5 minutes ago*

The question is, how can i update this TextView every minute without any disturbance to the ListView.

Like: *if i am looking at the ListView for 5 minutes, just this TextView alone must change from 1 min to 2 mins so on for every item visible*

**What i tried:**

1. set this TextView in **getView()** using `System.currentTimeMillis() - givenTime[position];`

but here the TextView won't get updated if i am not scrolling (not calling the getView) or changing the visibility of the items.

1. Use a **timeTask()** thread every 1 minute and try to update the TextView of every item

here the problem is i get an Exception:

```
android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

moreover i have no idea how to change the TextView for every ListView item from the Activity.

But this looks like a familiar case.

How can i achieve this?

Thank You

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use a `Handler` and its `postDelayed` method to invalidate the list's adapter as follows:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler()
handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        handler.postDelayed( this, 60 * 1000 );
    }
}, 60 * 1000 );
```

You must only update UI in the main (UI) thread.

By creating the handler in the main thread, you ensure that everything you post to the handler is run in the main thread also.

Comment: But doesn't notifyDataSetChanged(); works only if the data is changed??

Comment: It will refresh the list view, doesn't matter if data has been changed or not.

Comment: fine. It worked. Thanks a lot. But what i thought was usually applications will update only the specific TextView not the whole ListView item. Doesn't this cause any delay or UI freeze if the ListView item is too complicated? like if it contains 2-3 Images, 3-5 TextViews??

Comment: It will update every View in every visible ListView item, but it shouldn't be much of a problem. If you are worried about performance when rendering images, you can always check that the ImageView is empty before trying to make it display a (potentially) new image

Comment: and 1 last thing. So, this is the same behavior like "Refresh" button of an ActionBar??

Comment: The behaviour of a "Refresh" button is whatever you make it to be :-) But yes, this is one possible behaviour

Comment: No. I mean usually refresh button is to know if any new items are added to the List rather than just to check if the current items data is changed. So i must do the same in that case, but before that must call the server/db and get new data etc.., in the handler?

Comment: That depends on how you store your data. If you use a ContentProvider and your adapter is a CursorAdapter, the ListView automatically gets told to update whenever there are changes in the underlying data. If you use another kind of adapter, you need some other mechanism to detect changes

Comment: inside the `run()` should I call the volley and then notifyDataSetChanged ?

Comment: missing semi-colon after new Handler()

Answer (score 4):

You can also create custom `TextView` which updates it self every second or minute or hour. This can be done easily by creating class which extends `TextView` and add Handler inside that class. Benefits are that you don't have to update your whole ListView, TextView will update itself automatically.

Example:

```
public class TextViewTimeCounter extends TextView {
private long mStartTime = 0;
private long mTimeNow = 0;
private int mDelay = 0;
private String mPart1 = "";
private String mPart2 = "";

private Handler mHandler;

public TextViewTimeCounter(Context context) {
    super(context, null, 0);
}

public TextViewTimeCounter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public TextViewTimeCounter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public void startTimer(long delay, String part1, String part2){
    mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mTimeNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mDelay = delay;
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(r, delay);
    convertDatesToMinutes(mStartTime, mTimeNow);
}

public void stopTimer(){
    if(mHandler != null){
        mHandler = null;
        mStartTime = 0;
        mTimeNow = 0;
    }
}

public boolean isTimerRunning(){
    return mHandler == null? false : true;
}


Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        mTimeNow += mDelay;
        convertDatesToMinutes(mStartTime, mTimeNow);
        if(mHandler != null){
            mHandler.postDelayed(r, mDelay);
        }
    }
};



public void convertDatesToMinutes(long start, long end){
    long secs = (end - start);
    long minute = (secs / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
    long hour = (secs / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;
    String time = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%2d hours %2d minutes", hour, minute);

    setText(mPart1 + time + mPart2);
}
```

Usage:

```
TextViewTimeCounter timer = (TextViewTimeCounter)convertView.findViewById(R.id.start_logging_time_text);
timer.startTimer(10000, "Posted ", " ago");
```

Output will look like this:

```
 Posted 1 hours 5 minutes ago
```

If you want to display seconds also, change `convertDatesToMinutes(long start, long end)` method to this:

```
public void convertDatesToMinutes(long start, long end){
        long secs = (end - start);
        long second = (secs / 1000) % 60;
        long minute = (secs / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
        long hour = (secs / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;
        String time = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%2d hours %2d minutes %2d seconds", hour, minute, second);
        setText(mPart1 + time + mPart2);
}
```

Comment: How would you stop the timer in this example? In theory it would just be when the list removes the view, but it doesn't look like there's a way to do that.

Comment: If you use custom list adapter which extends BaseAdapter, you need to call ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); and in adapter getView(); method you call stopTimer();

Answer (score 3):

Use the built in TimerTask

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html

This is a solid way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

If you want repeat an action in the main thread in fractions of time you should use "schedule" method of the Time.class

```
mHandler = new Handler();
mTimer = new Timer();
mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // run main thread code
            }
        });
    }
}, DELAY_TIME, PERIOD_TIME);
```