# Android - update custom listview every minute in real time

Tags: android, listview

I know that in order to update Listview I have to use `notifyDataSetChanged()`. But, how can I update custom Listview every minute in real time?

For example, my app has created Listview at 05h:10m:20s and after 40 seconds it should updates Listview every one minute. In other words it should determines if current time have changed by one minute and than update Listview. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You could use handler for that purpose.
See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916084/android-update-listview-items-every-1-minute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916084/android-update-listview-items-every-1-minute)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you want to update your `ListView` every minute at second 0. If not, you should use other answers.

If so, you can try register broadcast receiver for `ACTION_TIME_TICK`.

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);

Context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}, intentFilter);
```

Do not forget to call `Context.unregisterReceiver()` at `onStop()` of your `Activity`

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should something like this:

```
private ListView listView;

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       listView.postDelayed(this, 60000);
   }
};

listView.postDelayed(r, 60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Works pretty well!

```
private ListView listView;
private ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter;
private Handler mainHandler;

//....
//Call method when start updating

public void updateListShedule () {
    if (handler == null) {
        handler = new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper())
   }
   handler.postDelayed ( new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          updateListShedule();
      }
   }, 10000);
}
```